# Can't echo a string in _POST form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, echo

I've made a simple form using HTML and PHP, but when I embed the "username" and "password" in my localhost and hit "Submit" the page just reloads and doesn't return "it works".

The code is use:

PHP

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

    echo "it works";
}
   
?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title> Document </title>
    
</head>
<body>
<form action="checkform.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please advise what am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `<? php` should be `<?php`

Comment: Also it should go to `checkform.php`, not reloading. Unless both the PHP and the HTML are already in checkform.php? It isn't clear, from your description.

Comment: Pity I can't add a giphy with a facepalm. Thank you ADyson

Comment: `UTC-8` should be `UTF-8`. Spend a bit more time checking for typos please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment, my mistake was the gap between "<?" and "php". Thank you for your comments!